# Get no. of array elements between certain values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to the find the number of array elements present in the array between 2 values in PHP     .

lets say this is my array =>

```
$a = array(1,2,3,5,10);
```

I want to find the length of array between 2 values i.e. 2 and 10. So the answer will be 3 in the case. If the highest value to be searched is present in the array it should be added in count.

also length of array between 2 and 9 is 2.

Hope I am clear with my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Allow me to ask, are there any restrictions on this? Like: You must not use a loop or something?

Comment: Between 4 and 10, it should be 2 or 1?

Comment: if you have same value in your array, lets say 2 in two places, then from where your array starts the count?

Comment: You could also use `array_filter();` to get the values you need (and then keep for later processing) and then `count()` or `sizeof()` to find the size of the filtered array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_filter()` to filter the array down to the matching elements, then use `count()` on the resulting filtered array.

```
$a = array(1,2,3,5,10);
print count(array_filter($a, function($e) {return ($e>=2 && $e<=10);}));
```

Hope that helps.

Note: The syntax I've used here, with the embedded function, requires PHP v5.3 or higher.

[EDIT]

Turn it into a simple callable function:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,5,10);
print countInRange(2,10);

function countInRange($min,$max) {
    return count(array_filter($a, function($e) use($min,$max) {return ($e>=$min && $e<=$max);}));
}
```

See PHP manual for more info on [`array_filter()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: i guess it should be `$e>2`, anyway +1

Comment: callable function doesn't use $max $min ($e>=2 && $e<=10)??

Comment: @Waygood - heh. good catch. I was typing too quick. fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++ ) {
  if( $a[$i] <= $max && $a[$i] >= $min )
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: You know, this would probably give him the entire array count. Because everything is either smaller than the maximum OR bigger than the minimum.

Comment: @ATaylor Oh, damn! Fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$min = 2;
$max = 10;

$a = array(1,2,3,5,10);

foreach($a as $val) {
    if($val > $min && $val <= $max) ++$count;
}
```

This should work, right? At least it will find all numbers, which are higher than your minimum but smaller/equal to your maximum.

Of course this also means, that an array of `1, 2, 9, 5` would return 2, since both 9 and 5 are greater than 2 and smaller than 10.